# Gitlab lists only current pipeline instead of all projects present in a particular folder

Tags: list, gitlab, project

I am trying to list all the projects present in particular folder but the script output list only my current project and does not include other projects.
Below is my .git-ci.yml code

```
script:
   - cd ..
   - pwd
   - ls
```

The expected output should be all the projects in the folder but it list only current project that is being built. I tired the same script in another project and it gave same ouput I.e current project being built.

Comment: CI is runing per project, so you cannot see all projects. Which problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to scan the workspace and parse some fields from .git-ci.yml of all the projects . Also when I lost the projects folder contents, it doesn't show .git-ci.yml file